# Should I be checking in these gradle files?

Tags: java, git, gradle

Should the following modified files be checked in into a repo? I am guessing not but since I am new to the tools around Java, I thought I'd ask.

```
    modified:   .gradle/3.5.1/fileContent/annotation-processors.bin
    modified:   .gradle/3.5.1/fileContent/fileContent.lock
    modified:   .gradle/3.5.1/taskHistory/fileHashes.bin
    modified:   .gradle/3.5.1/taskHistory/fileSnapshots.bin
    modified:   .gradle/3.5.1/taskHistory/jvmClassSignatures.bin
    modified:   .gradle/3.5.1/taskHistory/taskHistory.bin
    modified:   .gradle/3.5.1/taskHistory/taskHistory.lock
    modified:   .idea/workspace.xml
```

What gitignore rule will take care of any files from gradle that I don't want to check in?

I could just do a:

```
.gradle/
```

but I am worried that that might even ignore files that need to be checked in and since I am not sure, I thought it best to ask.

I did a:

```
.gradle/**/*.bin
.gradle/**/*.lock
```

but these files still show up as unstaged.

Comment: @GhostCat You're right. My apologies. Fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can ignore that folder. ([gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/api/gradle), [github/gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Gradle.gitignore))

More generally, if you were to delete the folder entirely, can you rebuild your project? If yes, you can ignore the resource regenerated by a build.

So, as a test, move `.gradle/` outside of your project (backup), and rebuilt it. If the `.gradle/` content is regenerated, that means it is safe to be ignored by the Git repo.

Comment: Thank you. Just one last question: Can I delete the `.gradle` folder altogether? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 I am saying, as a test, you can check if you can rebuild your project after having deleted the .gradle folder. If yes, that means it is safe to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

I thought Gradle should have some say about this; their documentation says the following:

> The project root directory contains all source files that are part of
> your project. In addition, it contains files and directories that are
> generated by Gradle such as .gradle and build. While the former are
> usually checked in to source control, the latter are transient files
> used by Gradle to support features like incremental builds.

While not explicit, it provides some hint that the `.gradle` and `build` directories *should not* be under source control.

See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html#dir:project_root